# Nginx Wordpress configuration issue on Ubuntu guest and Virtualbox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, wordpress

I have updated the question based on the suggestion from @Gerard H. Pille below.

First time setting this up. I have `Virtualbox` running `Ubuntu 18.04` on a `Win 10` host for a `wordpress` project.

My shared folder is mounted in `/media/sw_wp` and working

My projects folder contains one project only, at `/media/wp_sf/myproj`

I am using this `nginx` [config from here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/):

```
# Upstream to abstract backend connection(s) for php
upstream php {
        server unix:/tmp/php-cgi.socket;
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
        ## Your website name goes here.
        server_name myproj.com.au;

        ## Your only path reference.
        root /var/www/html/myproj;

        ## This should be in your http block and if it is, it's not needed here.
        index index.php;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location / {
                # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
                # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                include fastcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass php;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

I have created the symbolic link from `sites-available` to `sites-enabled` and I can see the link using `ls`.

`/var/www/html/myproj` contains my wordpress installation.

I have created a symlink from the share folder so that it now appears as:

```
/var/www/html/myproj
```

Everything else in the guest is `ubuntu + php 7.2 + nginx + mysql`

When I browse the project I get:

```
This site can’t be reached
myproj.com.au refused to connect.
```

On suggestion below the result of `nslookup myproj.com.au` is

```
Server 127.0.0.53
Server Address 127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: myproj.com.au
Address: 52.64....  // An IP I do not recognise
```

I can ping the guest from a `DOS window` in the Host and I get a response., so the environment is set up correctly.

```
ping myproj.com.au
```

What have I missed? Thanks.

Comment: How does myproj.com.au resolve?  Try "nslookup myproj.com.au".  What is the use of "/media/sw_wp"?  It isn't mentioned in nginx's config.  "/media/wp_sf/myproj" vs.  "root /media/sf_wp/myproj" ???

Comment: The `/media/.wp_sf` is where `Virtualbox` mounts the host shared folder. Ubuntu does not allow me to symlink `/var/www` to `/media/sf_wp` folder. Is there a different way to set this up?

Comment: Does the folder name change each time you type it?  Now it's "/media/.wp_sf" ?

Comment: Hi sorry, longest day! no, the folder name should always be `/media/sf_wp`. But see my update on your suggestions above. Thanks for helping.

Comment: What IP address does "ping myproj.com.au" give?  Different from nslookup?

Comment: BTW did you run the nslookup & ping on the windows host or the linux client?

Comment: I ran it on ubuntu guest

Comment: The ip on the host side is the correct '192.168.0.5', which matches the ip of the `bridged adapter` in `virtualbox` and what the `ubuntu` guest can see `ifconfig`. So the ip looks ok. Additionally, the host `myproj.com.au` is resolving on my host to the same ip.

Comment: next test (from the host!) : "telnet 192.168.0.5 80"  to see if you can contact nginx inside the guest.  I think you'll have to replace bridged by nat with port forwarding.

Comment: hey! It refuses to connect to SSH from my git window though I can see ssh server running on the guest. But connection refused is also what I get on the browser. I can ping the address, the fw is off (and I just reinstalled clean 18.04 to start again).

Comment: You reinstalled.  Yeah, was probably a lot easier than following my advice.

Comment: Hi Gerard, your advice showed me another problem around permissions, as my `/var/www/html` (shared from `win 10` host, symlinked) folder is permission denied. So I though I would reinstall but I ended up with this problem now. https://superuser.com/questions/1327055/virtualbox-ubuntu-18-04-permission-issue-to-symlinked-share-host-folder