# Virtualbox Ubuntu 18.04 permission issue to symlinked share host folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, permissions, symbolic-link

Trying to get a `Ubuntu 18.04` installation for `Wordpress` on a `Win 10` host. The host shares a folder with the VM, which is the root to multiple projects. This is a fresh VM built from the std `Ubuntu 18/04 LTS x64 Server` image.

I install `nginx` and I can see the `Welcome page`. I then delete the `/var/www/html` folder and re-create using a symlink to my shared folder:

```
sudo ln -s /media/sf_Wordpress /var/www/html
```

When I browse my server, I get `502 Bad Gateway`.

If I `cd` into `/var/www/hmtl` I get `permission denied`. If I change to `root` I can access the folder and list all files in the share.

My `nginx` log says:

```
papa@wp:~$ tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
2018/05/30 05:05:05 [crit] 766#766: *4 stat() "/var/www/html/mysite1/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.0.5, server: mysite1.com.au, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "mysite1.com.au"
2018/05/30 05:05:05 [crit] 766#766: *4 stat() "/var/www/html/mysite1/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.0.5, server: mysite1.com.au, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "mysite1.com.au"
2018/05/30 05:05:05 [error] 766#766: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.5, server: mysite1.com.au, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "mysite1.com.au"
2018/05/30 05:05:05 [crit] 766#766: *4 connect() to unix:/tmp/php-cgi.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.5, server: mysite1.com.au, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php-cgi.socket:", host: "mysite1.com.au"
```

I added `www-data` to `vboxsf` group. No difference.

Checking the `nginx` process tells me it is being run by `root`:

```
papa@wp:~$ ps -eo pid,comm,euser,supgrp | grep nginx
 1888 nginx           root     root
 1891 nginx           www-data www-data,vboxsf
```

Using the suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500932/what-are-the-correct-permissions-for-my-site-that-is-now-served-by-nginx), I ran:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

But it made no difference. Still `502 Bad gateway`.

Running `nginx -t` shows:

```
papa@wp:~$ nginx -t
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2018/05/30 07:37:21 [warn] 1905#1905: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
2018/05/30 07:37:21 [emerg] 1905#1905: open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/fca.conf" failed (13: Permission denied) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

My `nginx` config `fca.conf` for this site is:

```
# Upstream to abstract backend connection(s) for php
upstream php {
        server unix:/tmp/php-cgi.socket;
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
        ## Your website name goes here.
        server_name mysite1.com.au;

        ## Your only path reference.
        root /var/www/html/mysite1;

        ## This should be in your http block and if it is, it's not needed here.
        index index.php;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location / {
                # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
                # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                include fastcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass php;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, x64. I added the shared folder via `VBox` interface (auto-mount, permanent). Then created a `simlink` so the projects / shared folder is "sees" as `/var/www/html`. Doing an `ls` here shows the project on the host. It seems like my user `papa` and `www-data` cannot access the content of the shared folder pointed to by the `simlink`

Comment: "Checking the nginx process tells me it is being run by root:"  No it does not.  It is started by root, but runs as www-data.  You would be mad nowadays to run a web-server as root.

Comment: Hi Gerard, this is just local dev env, so I just want it working, production will not be in a VM environment like this.

Comment: OK, added something to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not forget your shared folder is not really a linux filesystem, only looks a bit like it.   Copy everything from the share to a real linux filesystem, and try again.

Don't change the properties of the link

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

Change the properties of the origin

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /media/sf_Wordpress
```

Comment: Hi Gerard, but this setup is working in Homestead for my Laravel projects. These sit on my Windows shared folder, yet are visible and executable by nginx (www-data) from the guest Ubuntu side.

Comment: Hi Gerard, the initial issue seems to point to `nginx` not having write access to `/var/log/nginx/error.log` also. Why would a vanilla installation have these access issues?

Comment: That was papa running nginx, not www-data. Try "sudo nginx -t".

Comment: Ahh got it! Thanks for that. Got rid of the error

Comment: Then you could perhaps accept the answer?

Comment: Hi Gerard, I am still getting permission denied in my nginx log and I get a 404 page now when accessing the server via browser

Comment: rebooted and now it works?!

Comment: Machine or virtualbox client?